# Tools/Techniques to use our ability to think spatially

Tags: user-interface, spatial

What software/UI techniques can leverage our spatial memory?  I think and remember in physical space, often the location of something is as important as it's content. For instance I keep an untidy desk, but I know where to find things, I use different parts of my (multiscreen) desktop for different windows/icons. I annotate books (with post its) and can remember facing page, top/bottom etc. In the good old days we used to file things so we could find them later, now we use search, but that doesn't really use our spatial abilities. Google maps etc are brilliant but they're only really being used for the real real world, what about our internal locations? How can we leverage the wet ware to best advantage.

EDIT -> I've thought about a code tool that would profile the running code and then build a visualisation with classes/methods scaled to match their use, with large/small motorways/footpaths between them. Spatial layout still escapes me though - UI at the top, DB at the bottom, but how do you position a class in 3D based on it's usage?

Comment: Great question. I attended a great lecture that discussed that we struggle to track big software projects because they're so much less tangible than - say - building a bridge. I was thinking about what you could do to make tangible the state of a software project that we could rely on senses. I was thinking about a tool that releases a bad smell based on analysis of a codeset to make the notion of codesmell something real.

Comment: Love the comment, never thought about smell but it'd work and be so much better than bloody automatic airfreshners.

Comment: Realistically these things have to be subtle so as not to draw too much attention and cause distraction. You could take advantage of any of the senses. The brain is remarkably quick at learning to see through the raw sensory data to the meaning of it. See http://tonguevision.blogspot.com/ for a great example.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic since it's not code per say but I've built my own tools to translate some of out complicated XML config files into DOT format and run them through Graphviz so that I could visualise them. We were able to strip out lots of pointless stuff from them after just looking at them.

Wetware win :o)